# Building my first executable software (Any idea is welcome and thank you so much in advance!)

Tags: reactjs, database, electron, react-fullstack

Hi professionals & experts, I'm looking for ideas on how to start my first executable software

I'm trying to build software for a hospital. I just graduated from College so I'm lacking in many ways when it comes to deploying software for public use.
I will be building and hosting software from the US but my user's hospital is in Southeast Asia Region and they'll be using it from there.

**Software Description**
It will be a data management software where it keeps track of quantities in a hospital(like pharmacy or surgery uses).
It will have a flexible/friendly UI and good security for user login.
It will require a good database to store thousands of medicine, surgery products.
It can handle user manual entry of patient and doctor's information in a day-to-day basics.

**Plan**
For front end, I plan to use Reactjs.

For the database, I don't have the budget, so I can't afford to pay for big services but I would still like to try with everything I have.

To deploy, I planned to use Electron, I heard it is convenient and a lot of industries use it.

**Big Questions**

1. what kind of database should I use?
2. how can I connect the database to my software?
3. How can I host both server and database in the US and have users in another region use it without any struggle?
4. Hospitals will have thousands of data, so manual user input to the database would take a long time(What kind of solutions do I have for this?)
5. Is React for the front end a good choice?
6. Is Electron a good choice to deploy?
7. Are there already existing open-source software that I can just use and mod?
8. What other fields do I need to research more?

**Note**
I don't expect to get all the answers at once but thank you so much for contributing your ideas to helping me improve my skills and experiences.
If the info above is lacking to give me a good answer, please comment and I will fill out more information to the post.

Again, thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: Please read [ask]